# Using the SUM OVER clause, how to check sum over period only when output is not greater than a certain value, otherwise use current month value?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

Sample data:

```
select date, agent, sales
from agentsales

date                    agent   sales
2021-01-03 00:00:00.000 Agent A 10
2021-02-05 00:00:00.000 Agent A 15
2021-03-10 00:00:00.000 Agent A 10
2021-01-05 00:00:00.000 Agent B 5
2021-02-06 00:00:00.000 Agent B 28
2021-03-10 00:00:00.000 Agent B 5
2021-01-02 00:00:00.000 Agent C 35
2021-02-04 00:00:00.000 Agent C 25
2021-03-08 00:00:00.000 Agent C 15
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 Agent D 5
2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 Agent D 35
2021-03-10 00:00:00.000 Agent D 31
```

I want to get the counts of agents who have crossed 30 sales, such that **if they have never crossed a total of 30 sales then consider sum over current and previous months, otherwise only current month.**

Expected output:

```
YrMon  Count_Agent_more_than_30_sales
Jan21  1
Feb21  2
Mar21  2
```

Logic:

```
Jan21 - 1 since only C has crossed 30 sales
Feb21 - 2 since B and D have crossed 30 sales. Agent D has crossed the 30 mark in the month, and B has crossed over period for first time. C is not considered as it previously crossed the 30 mark.
Mar21 - 2 since A and D have crossed 30 sales. Agent A has crossed mark over period for 1st time. D has crossed for the month. B is not considered as periodic case was already considered in last month. C is not considered as it already crossed 30 mark last month.
```

As mentioned above, I want to get the counts of agents who have crossed 30 sales, such that **if they have never crossed a total of 30 sales then consider sum over current and previous months, otherwise only current month.**

My query to calculate sum over period:

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR) YRMON, AGENT, SUM(SALES) SALES
  FROM AgentSales
  GROUP BY  CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR), AGENT
  )
  SELECT *, SUM(SALES) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT ORDER BY YRMON) SUMOVERPERIOD FROM CTE
  ORDER BY 2,1

YRMON   AGENT   SALES   SUMOVERPERIOD
2021 1  Agent A 10      10
2021 2  Agent A 15      25
2021 3  Agent A 10      35
2021 1  Agent B 5       5
2021 2  Agent B 28      33
2021 3  Agent B 5       38
2021 1  Agent C 35      35
2021 2  Agent C 25      60
2021 3  Agent C 15      75
2021 1  Agent D 5       5
2021 2  Agent D 35      40
2021 3  Agent D 31      71
```

Now I am trying to apply the logic on the calculated sum:

```
   ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR) YRMON, AGENT, SUM(SALES) SALES
  FROM AgentSales
  GROUP BY  CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR), AGENT
  )
  SELECT *, SUM(SALES) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT ORDER BY YRMON) SUMOVERPERIOD,
  CASE WHEN SUM(SALES) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT ORDER BY YRMON)>30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CALC
  FROM CTE
  ORDER BY 2,1

YRMON   AGENT   SALES   SUMOVERPERIOD   CALC
2021 1  Agent A 10      10              0
2021 2  Agent A 15      25              0
2021 3  Agent A 10      35              1
2021 1  Agent B 5       5               0
2021 2  Agent B 28      33              1
2021 3  Agent B 5       38              1
2021 1  Agent C 35      35              1
2021 2  Agent C 25      60              1
2021 3  Agent C 15      75              1
2021 1  Agent D 5       5               0
2021 2  Agent D 35      40              1
2021 3  Agent D 31      71              1
```

This query is always considering sum over current and previous period.

How to check whether the sales has previously crossed the 30 sales mark and for such cases to exclude doing the sum over period? For example can we apply LAG on the result of the SUM OVER column?

Comment: AGENT B  shouldn't be at Mar21  list ? 5+28 , or you just eliminate it because its listed at Feb21 ?

Comment: I don't understand the logic: are you including *all* agents >=30 up to this point (in which case why aren't the results `1,3,4`) or only the agents who crossed >=30 that month (in which case it should be `1,2,1`), why are you counting Agent D twice?

Comment: Ali - since Agent B has not crossed 30 before, so consider sum over period.

Comment: Charlieface - the counts are as of the respective month end. All agents >= 30 upto this point provided that the agent has never crossed 30. If has crossed 30, then don't sum over period, and consider for respective month only. In which month are you'd saying that I have counted Agent D twice please?

Comment: `Mar21` you count A and D, but in `Feb21` you already counted D

Comment: Right because D has crossed 30 in that month (Mar) it is to be counted. Since it crossed 30 without considering previous periods.

Comment: In which month, Feb21 or Mar21? I see it crossing in Feb21 so it shouldn't be counted again

Comment: Mar21. As mentioned in question - `I want to get the counts of agents who have crossed 30 sales, such that if they have never crossed a total of 30 sales then consider sum over current and previous months, otherwise only current month.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if one of these fits your needs (I think the description confusion)

#### Option 1

```
-- If you want to count only the first time [agent] crossed 30 sales
;With MyCTE01 as (
    SELECT 
        [date] = EOMONTH([date], -1),
        [agent],[sales], 
        S = SUM([sales]) OVER (PARTITION BY [agent] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
    FROM [AgentSales]
),
MyCTE02 as (
    SELECT [date],[agent],[sales], S
    FROM MyCTE01
    -- The idea of using "and S - [sales] < 30" instead of ROW_NUMBER came from @Charlieface, but it is better to do the work on DATE data type and not on string
    WHERE S > 30 and S - [sales] < 30
)
SELECT DATENAME(month,[Date]), YEAR([Date]), COUNT(*) 
FROM MyCTE02
GROUP BY [date]
GO
```

#### Option 2

```
-- If you want to count all the [agent] crossed 30 sales till now
;With MyCTE01 as (
    SELECT 
        [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH([date], -1)),
        [agent],[sales], 
        S = SUM([sales]) OVER (PARTITION BY [agent] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
    FROM [AgentSales]
)
,MyCTE02 as (
    SELECT [date],[agent],[sales], S
    FROM MyCTE01
    WHERE S > 30
)
SELECT DATENAME(month,[Date]), YEAR([Date]), COUNT(*) 
FROM MyCTE02
GROUP BY [date]
GO
```

### Option 3

```
-- If you want to count only the first time [agent] crossed 30 sales or when the sales or over 30
;With MyCTE01 as (
    SELECT 
        [date] = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH([date], -1)),
        [agent],[sales], 
        S = SUM([sales]) OVER (PARTITION BY [agent] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
    FROM [AgentSales]
)
,MyCTE02 as (
    SELECT [date],[agent],[sales], S
    FROM MyCTE01
    -- The idea of using "and S - [sales] < 30" instead of ROW_NUMBER came from @Charlieface, but it is better to do the work on DATE data type and not on string
    WHERE (S > 30 and S - [sales] < 30) or sales > 30
)
SELECT DATENAME(month,[Date]), YEAR([Date]), COUNT(*) 
FROM MyCTE02
GROUP BY [date]
GO
```

[image]

### DDL+DML

```
USE tempdb
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [AgentSales]
GO
CREATE TABLE [AgentSales](id INT IDENTITY(1,1), [date] DATE, agent VARCHAR(100), sales INT)
GO
INSERT [AgentSales]([date],[agent],[sales]) VALUES
('2021-01-03 00:00:00.000','Agent A', 10),
('2021-02-05 00:00:00.000','Agent A', 15),
('2021-03-10 00:00:00.000','Agent A',10),
('2021-01-05 00:00:00.000','Agent B',5 ),
('2021-02-06 00:00:00.000','Agent B',28),
('2021-03-10 00:00:00.000','Agent B',5 ),
('2021-01-02 00:00:00.000','Agent C',35),
('2021-02-04 00:00:00.000','Agent C',25),
('2021-03-08 00:00:00.000','Agent C',15),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','Agent D',5 ),
('2021-02-02 00:00:00.000','Agent D',35),
('2021-03-10 00:00:00.000','Agent D',31)
GO

SELECT [id],[date],[agent],[sales]
FROM [AgentSales]
GO
```

Comment: Expected output mentioned in question is 1,2,2

Comment: In this case, I do not understand the logic and how you get this value from the sample data. Please explain each value in the result how exactly you got it from the source sample data

Comment: I have explained against the results in my question

Comment: OK, i think that I got your needs now. I will update the answer and add option 3 which is what you actually need (I think)

Comment: Nice. That's working for my sample data, I will test more - can you tell me what this does `(S > 30 and S - [sales] < 30)` please?

Comment: `(S > 30 and S - [sales] < 30)`: this take the first one that pass 30. `S` is sum including this row and `S-sales` is the sum without this row. if this rows is above 30 but not the first one then the `S-sales` will also be above 30 and this mean we do not want it, since we want only first one above 30

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this should work for you

- You need to pre-aggregate the sales per `agent` and `month`, then get a running sum of that aggregate
- Then simply check if each row has crossed over in this month by comparing the current data with the running sum

```sql
SELECT
  YrMon = FORMAT(Month, 'yyyy MM'),
  Count_Agent_more_than_30_sales =
        COUNT(CASE WHEN SumOverPeriod >= 30 AND SumOverPeriod - sales < 30 OR sales >= 30 THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT
      Month = EOMONTH(date),
      agent,
      sales = SUM(sales),
      SumOverPeriod = SUM(SUM(sales)) OVER (PARTITION BY agent ORDER BY EOMONTH(date)
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM AgentSales
    GROUP BY EOMONTH(date), agent
) sales
GROUP BY Month;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf047571832e03c03f03d85cce2d5e66)

Comment: The expected output given in the question is 1,2,2; but this query is giving output 1,1,1

Comment: I get 1,2,1 for the data you provided, see fiddle, and as I said, you are double-counting Agent D

Comment: I have explained in the question why it is 1,2,2. @Ronen seems to have given correct answer.

Comment: Ah I think I've got you now, have updated.